# Python or Excel: How can you compare 2 columns and then write the value of a 3rd column in a new column?

Tags: python, excel, data-science

I have 2 tables that look like this:

**Table 1**

```
| ID | Tel. |   Name  |
|:--:|:----:|:-------:|
| 1  | 1234 | Denis   |
| 2  | 4567 | Michael |
| 3  | 3425 | Peter   |
| 4  | 3242 | Mary    |
```

**Table 2**

```
| ID | Contact Date |
|:--:|:------------:|
| 1  | 2014-05-01   |
| 2  | 2003-01-05   |
| 3  | 2020-01-10   |
| 4  | NULL         |
```

Now I want to Compare the **First Table** with the **second table** with the `ID` column to look if `contact 1` is already in the list where people were contacted. After this, I want to write the `Contact Date` into the first table to see the last contact date in the main table.

How would I do this?

Thanks for any answers!!

Comment: vlookup() will check for an id in table 1 in table 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that might get your interest using ***MySQL***; Then if you want to implement it into **Python** will be easy.

**First, Let's create our `T1` *Table* AS CODED**

```
create table T1(
    id integer primary key,
    tel integer, 
    name varchar(100)
    );

create table T2(
    id integer primary key,
    contactDate date
    );
```

**Second Table `T2`**

```
create table T2(
    id integer primary key,
    contactDate date
    );
```

**Insertion Of `T1` AND `T2`:**

```
-- Table 'T1' Insertion

insert into T1(id, tel, name) VALUES 
    (1, 1234, "Denis"),
    (2, 4567, "Michael"),
    (3, 3425,"Peter"),
    (4, 3242, "Mary");

-- Table 'T2' Insertion              
              
insert into T2(id, contactDate) VALUES 
    (1, 20140105),
    (2, 20030105),
    (3, 20201001),
    (4, Null);
```

**Then, Create `T3` With the Select Statement for both tables using `INNER JOIN` For `Joins` Results**
[image: INNER JOIN]

```
CREATE TABLE T3 AS
    SELECT T1.id, T1.name, T1.tel, T2.contactDate
    FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.id;
```

**Then, `SELECT` to check the results**

`select * from T3;`

***OUTPUT***

```
| id |   name  | tel  | contactDate |
|:--:|:-------:|------|-------------|
| 1  | Denis   | 1234 | 2014-01-05  |
| 2  | Michael | 4567 | 2003-01-05  |
| 3  | Peter   | 3425 | 2020-10-01  |
| 4  | Mary    | 3242 | NULL        |
```

I Hope This Helps. I was really trying to merge the `T3`---> `contactDate` with `T1` for like 3 hours. But it was process heavy. I will attach Links that could help you more.

### Reference

[INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

[SQL ALTER TABLE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

[SQL Server INSERT Multiple Rows](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/)

[INSERT INTO SELECT statement overview and examples](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-insert-into-select-statement-overview-and-examples/)

[SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)